# Replacing DIV using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

I’m building a sortable biography section for a client, using jQuery.

I was originally using just two bios (first person, and third person), and I had it working perfectly:

```
$("a#first").click(function(){
    $("div.third").fadeOut("",function(){
        $("div.first").fadeIn("");
    });
});
```

Here’s a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vp7BL/1/

Now we’ve changed directions, and are sorting with three different bio lengths (short, medium, long). For some reason, I can’t get this to work. I assumed it would just be a matter of adding the extra div into the selector (line 2 below), but it’s super laggy.

```
$("a#short").click(function(){
        $("div.medium, div.long").fadeOut("",function(){
        $("div.short").fadeIn("");
    }); 
});
```

Here’s a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vp7BL/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [update](http://jsfiddle.net/Vp7BL/2/) to your fiddle. I would absolutely position the bios, this way they all start at the same point vertically, which removes the 'jump' when transitioning them in and out.

```
.short, .medium, .long {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, it's probably best to have an "active" class for the current active bio, it'll make this easier to manage.

```
$('a#short').click(function() {
  $('div.active').removeClass("active").fadeOut("", function() {
    $('div.short').addClass("active").fadeIn("");
  });
});
```

It would be even better for you to come up with a way to make the code more modular so you won't have to do a change to the JS every time you need to add/remove a bio.

lets say my link is set up like

```
<ul id="bionav">
  <a class="bio-link" data-bio="short">short</a>
  <a class="bio-link" data-bio="med">med</a>
  <a class="bio-link" data-bio="long">long</a>
</ul>
<ul id="biodisplay">
  <div class="bio-link short">short</div>
  <div class="bio-link med">med</div>
  <div class="bio-link long">long</div>
</ul>
```

you can control your set doing something like

```
$('#bionav').on('click', '.bio-link', function() {
  var $bioDisplay = $('#biodisplay'),
  $targetBio = $(this).attr('data-bio'); //if ie doesn't matter you can do .data('bio');
  $active = $bioDisplay.find('.active');

  if ($active != undefined) {
    $active.removeClass('active').fadeOut("", showBio($targetBio));
  } else {
    showBio($targetBio);
  }
});

function showBio(bio) {
  bio.addClass('active').fadeIn("");
}
```

this also does some event delegation for you so you attach 1 event to the dom rather than 3

Also taking into consideration Josh's suggestion, you wouldn't need to make the fadeIn a callback to the fadeOut, you could initiate them at the same time to have a crossfade.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two divs displayed at once? Because otherwise I don't understand why would you fade out two of them? The idea is as it follows:
1. Add a class (you are already doing that but in the wrong place) to the div that it is currently displayed (lets say the class name is "selected") 
2. When a tab is clicked, select the element with "selected" class and fade it out. In the callback you provide to the fadeout also remove the class selected from the element that was displayed and put it to the tab you just clicked on.

And, of course there is always jquery-ui.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of refactoring that pertains to your "design". You can keep your markup exactly the same, with the addition of [Josh Rutherford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658803/josh-rutherford)'s `postion: absolute` CSS style. I wanted to post this to allow you to see how this code could be more easily managed (as well as fixing your actual problem).

The CSS:

```
.short, .medium, .long {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px; /* whatever you prefer */
}
```

The JS:

```
$("a#short, a#medium, a#long").on("click", function() {
    var elid = $(this).attr('id');
    // Run getTab based on id attribute
    getTab(elid);
});

function getTab(tab, speed=500) {
  // Select the current tab
  var the_tab = $("#" + tab);

  // Select the current tab's matching content div
  var content = $("."+tab);

  // Push sibling tabs' classes into an array
  // Tab id value matches with respective div class value
  sibs = [];

  the_tab.siblings().each(function () {
      sibs.push('.' + $(this).attr('id'));
      // Deselect sibling tabs
      $(this).removeClass('selected');
  });

  // Fade out siblings
  $(sibs.join(",")).fadeOut(speed, function() {
      // Fade in current tab and add selected class
      the_tab.addClass('selected');
      content.fadeIn(speed);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

The main problem here is that you should absolute positioning `.short, .medium and .long` class, that way you will avoid the issue with the lack. Also, you should put it inside another class. That way would be easy to select it with jQuery if you add an `.extralong` class in the future.

After few changes your code should look like this:

#### Jquery:

```
$('.toggles a').click(function(e) {
    //Never forget this
    e.preventDefault();
    //if click on the selected do nothing
    if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
        return false;
    //let fadeOut all the texts 
    $('.short, .medium, .long').fadeOut('10');
    //let fadeIn the clicked one
    $('.'+$(this).attr('id')).fadeIn();
    //remove all the selected class
    $('.toggles a').removeClass('selected');
    //add the selected class to the clicked one
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

#### CSS:

```
.short, .medium, .long{
    position: absolute;
}
```

#### Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vp7BL/3/